# Python dictionary find value with the attribute of a composite key

Tags: python, dictionary

A dictionary has a custom class as the key.
I would like to search for the existence of a key by using the value of the **hash** function rather than the object.

The below snippet prints None, None, None. The reason is the **eq** checks for the instance. However, I am not able to remove the isInstance check (interpreter fails)

Any suggestions on how I could get the result to print None, object one, object two ?

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.age
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other,person) and other.age == self.age
    
    def __str__(self):
        return 'name: ' + self.name + ' age: ' + self.age
    
class find:
    def run(age):
        d = {obj('hi',10) : 'one', obj('bye',20) : 'two'}
        item = d.get(age, None)
        print(item)

one = person('one',1)
two = person('two', 2)

d = {one : 'one', two: 'two'}

print(d.get(0, None))
print(d.get(1, None))
print(d.get(2, None))
```

Comment: You would have to add an additional check to your `__eq__` method that returned `True` if `other` was an integer and was equal to `self.age`

Comment: You *can't* search by hash value, that isn't how a dictionary works. Create another dictionary, that maps hash value to the object (taking care for possible duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

In fact python allow same hash value in one same dict.

You can try

```
d = {one : 'one', two: 'two', 1: 'one'}
```

This will show no error.

If you want to konw why. You should search how python achieve dict with hash table.

In your code. You can just get Your value with:

```
d[one]
```

or

```
d.get(one, None)
```

Comment: This is not what I want to do. I would like to search based on age- which is an integer

Comment: In my explanation you can see with one hash value, there could be multiply values in a dict. So you can not search by hash value. If you acheive your own hash table, then you could have that funciton.